# Query to display total row count returned, but with a limited result set

Tags: sql, teradata

For QA purposes, I need to provide a sample of error records as well the total number of errors records. For background, this sample needs to be limited to ~1000 records since the query results are stored in an Excel `recordSet` object and output to a text file. This sounds very clunky (and is) but there are reasons for it.

I know I can do:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
 primaryKey
,expectedValue
,actualValue
,totalErrors
FROM errorTable
INNER JOIN (SELECT count(*) as totalErrors FROM errorTable) AS tmp
    ON 1 = 1
```

But I'd like a more efficient way since `errorTable` is actually a subquery that finds all the error records and can get pretty computationally expensive.

Comment: You could also cross join and not use the 1= 1

Comment: I tried that first but kept getting a syntax error, I still have no idea why.

Comment: OK, I posted an example of how to do the cross join if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use window functions:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 primaryKey, expectedValue, actualValue,
       COUNT(*) OVER () as totalErrors
FROM errorTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cross join like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
  primaryKey,
  expectedValue,
  actualValue,
  tmp.totalErrors
FROM errorTablem, (SELECT count(*) as totalErrors FROM errorTable) AS tmp
```